# Get Node.js to read and print data from all text files in directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, readfile

I'm trying to get node to open every text file in a directory so I can put them into arrays. I've tried readdir and readdirSync and it (was) getting a list of the file names, but I want it to print the file contents too and everything I do is making it worse. (I think I want readdirSync so it gets all the data before it does anything else?)

```
var filenames = [];
var fs = require("fs");

var path = require("path");

var p = "6er/"
fs.readdirSync(p, function (err, files) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    files.map(function (file) {
        return path.join(p, file);
    }).filter(function (file) {
        return fs.statSync(file).isFile();
    }).forEach(function (file) {
       filenames.push(file);
        console.log(file);
    });
});

for(var f in filenames){
 fs.readFile(p+f, function (err, data){
            var results = data;
            console.log(results);
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Readdirsync doesnt work like that, it doesnt use a callback as it is Sync... please use readdir: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_callback

also to this problem I recommend a way to handle all the async so you dont get a problem blocking the thread while it read all those files, please study this package: https://github.com/caolan/async

if you need more help add comments and I will reply